# Have cron email me only on actual Git errors

Tags: git, cron, sendmail, stderr

I'm running a cronjob that pulls a Git repository and pushes it to another location. I would like to have the cronjob run silently, but whenever something fails I would like to be notified by mail. Conveniently, cron's default setting is to send out a mail whenever the stderr buffer is not empty.

The output of `git pull > /dev/null` is indeed void if the local branch is up-to-date, but `git push > /dev/null` isn't:

```
$ git push > /dev/null
Everything up-to-date
```

This results in a mail by cron on every `git push`. I do *not* want to neglect stderr like

```
$ git push > /dev/null 2>&1
```

since I'd like to be notified of actual failures.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [git push](http://jk.gs/git-push.html) man page:

```
   -q, --quiet
       Suppress all output, including the listing of updated refs, 
       unless an error occurs. Progress is not reported to the 
       standard error stream.
```

There are more commands in git that let you surpress all non-error output.